# JS regex not returning all matched group

Tags: javascript, regex

My string is as follows:

```
var data = "Validation failed: Attachments document 01april2015_-_Copy.csv has contents that are not what they are reported to be, Attachments document 01april2015.csv has contents that are not what they are reported to be"
```

My regex:

```
var regex = /Validation failed:(?:(?:,)* Attachments document ([^,]*) has contents that are not what they are reported to be)+/;
```

result:

```
data.match(regex)
```

> ["Validation failed: Attachments document 01april2015_-_Copy.csv has contents that are not what they are reported to be, Attachments document 01april2015.csv has contents that are not what they are reported to be", "01april2015.csv"]

```
data.match(regex).length == 2
```

> true

Expected result:

```
data.match(regex)
```

> ["Validation failed: Attachments document 01april2015_-*Copy.csv has contents that are not what they are reported to be, Attachments document 01april2015.csv has contents that are not what they are reported to be", "01april2015*-_Copy.csv", "01april2015.csv"]

```
data.match(regex).length == 3
```

> true

I am unable to comprehend why is it not returning the first filename(`01april2015_-_Copy.csv`) after match. Any sort of explanation would be sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In JS, there is no `Captures` collection as in C#, thus, I suggest using a shortened regex with `g` option and use it with `exec` in order not to lose captured texts:

```js
var re = /Attachments document ([^,]*) has contents that are not what they are reported to be/g; 
var str = 'Validation failed: Attachments document 01april2015_-_Copy.csv has contents that are not what they are reported to be, Attachments document 01april2015.csv has contents that are not what they are reported to be';
var m;
var arr = [str];
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    arr.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(arr);
```

Note that a shortest possible pattern that can match the desired substring can be used to look for multiple matches. We cannot use [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) because:

> If the regular expression includes the `g` flag, the method returns an Array containing all matched substrings rather than match objects. **Captured groups are not returned.**
>
> if you want to obtain capture groups and the global flag is set, you need to use `RegExp.exec()` instead.

See the [`RegExp#exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) behavior with `/g`:

> If your regular expression uses the `"g"` flag, you can use the `exec()` method multiple times to find successive matches in the same string.
>
> If the match succeeds, the `exec()` method returns an array and updates properties of the regular expression object. The **returned array has** the matched text as the first item, and then **one item for each capturing parenthesis that matched containing the text that was captured**.

Comment: Well, I think all the information you need is available at the [`RegExp` MDN Reference resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp). I have added more explanations to the question.